# TextBlock inside MenuItem does not became gray if MenuItem is Disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

If I use this code:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuSave" Header="Save" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

when `MenuSave` is disabled (in real code by a `RoutedUICommand` programmatically), the `Header` is disabled and text is gray.

But if I need more text like here:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuSaveAs" IsEnabled="False">
     <MenuItem.Header >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="Save as"/>
                   <TextBlock> ...</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
     </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

In this case, the `Header` is disabled but text is not gray.

How can I obtain text gray with composite text?

This is just simplified code to explain the problem, the real code is combination of translated terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `TextBlock` thorough a [`HeaderTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.headertemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), the color will be applied for the disabled state. By the way, you can use multiple [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)s instead, so the same `TextBlock` is populated. If you bind a data item as `Header`, you can bind its properties in the template to the `Run`s.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuSaveAs" IsEnabled="False">
   <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Save as"/>
            <Run> ...</Run>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Alternatively, if you need to format a string with a bound property, use [`HeaderStringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.headerstringformat?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuSaveAs"
          IsEnabled="False"
          Header="{Binding NameOfTheSavedItem}"
          HeaderStringFormat="Save as {0}...">
```

---

If you really insist on setting the header directly, a workaround would be to bind the `Foreground` of `TextBlock` explicitly to the `TextElement.Foreground` of the `ContentPresenter` in the `MenuItem` control template. You can bind it on each `TextBlock` or add an implicit style that applies to all `TextBlock`s in scope automatically. Please note the word *all*.

```
<Menu>
   <Menu.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding (TextElement.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"/>
      </Style>
   </Menu.Resources>
   <MenuItem x:Name="MenuSaveAs"
             IsEnabled="True">
      <MenuItem.Header>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0" Text="Save as"/>
            <TextBlock Padding="0" Text="..."/>
         </StackPanel>
      </MenuItem.Header>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

---

Please be aware that I suggest to use a single `TextBlock` with `Run`s for sentences or paragraphs in general, because panels with multiple `TextBlock`s result in incorrect spacing and alignment that do not match the typesetting that `TextBlock` and other document related types provide. It usually looks odd and disjointed and does not take into account the characteristics of a font.

Comment: @Ricky I have added a workaround that might be suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about my solution with <Label Padding="0"..>, instead of <TextBlock ..>?

Comment: @Ricky Although that works, a `Label` is not a `TextBlock`, it serves a different purpose and behaves differently. I would not recommend it in general, but in the end it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an other easy way using <Label Padding="0"..>, instead af <TextBlock ..>:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuSaveAs" IsEnabled="False">
<MenuItem.Header >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Padding="0" Content="Save as"/>
        <Label Padding="0" Content="..."/>
    </StackPanel>
</MenuItem.Header>
```